# Can you use Microsoft 365/ Xrm SDK with .NetCore?

Tags: asp.net-core, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I am trying to make use of the new Web API features used within .NetCore and reference the Microsoft Dynamics CRM SDK.

Does anyone know if this is possible as it doesn't seem to work with .NetCore and I get an error when adding any NuGet packages as they require .net 4.5*

I'm hoping there is a way of doing this but if not I will need to convert the .NetCore API project to use the full .net framework.

Comment: Unlikely, unless it targets `netstandard1.x` or `portable-net451+win8` and nuget doesn't show any of it http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies/

Comment: Not to worry I saw something new and shiny and wanted an excuse to play around with it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not currently supported as the Dynamics 365 SDK does not support .NET Core